# SignalR runs on visual studio expres but not on iis

Tags: signalr

this is the error message 
SCRIPT5022: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. 
this is my project link :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=12bo73vYOEODXR9lY3tKmIGj7z0_Q1b0L

Comment: Please include the error message and the code you tried to use in the question. Don't make the users download, or open your code on different page.

Comment: js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                                                                                                                                                                             Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

Comment: And now the part with the error? Or where you are trying to get something out of client. Edit the question with that piece of code.

Comment: this is the problem ,  <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>, it faild to find this resource , the program works on iis express but not on the local iis

Comment: You should post code (Not the import part) of the actual error. And you should do it on your main question. Not on comments.

Comment: Add program code, We are here for solutions, not for to download your code and find errors for you.

Answer (score 0):

May be your application not running.
Add this settings ==>

```
   <appSettings>
     <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
        <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="SignalRChat.Startup" />
    </appSettings>
```

behind the `<configuration>` in your `web.config` to startup your `owin` application.
**EDITED ==>**
or learn more SignalR Windows supported platform here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms

Your application work(s) fine in Windows 8.1 ==>
[image]

Comment: which windows platform you are trying to use signalR ?